# How do I install the USB driver for Nexus One on Windows 7 for debugging purposes?

Tags: android, debugging, usb, driver, nexus-one

I have implemented a simple Android application that I now would like to test on a real device. I have a Nexus One.

In the Android Eclipse plugin, I have downloaded and installed the USB driver (revision 3) package. But when I connect my Nexus One to my PC (running Windows 7) using the USB cable, a message box pops up and shows that "No driver found" for "Nexus One".

[image: Driver Software Installation]

I have activated **USB Debugging** on my device. And when I run `adb devices` on my PC, it just prints `List of devices attached` and no devices are listed. And if I use **Device Manages** in Windows, and tries to update the driver for "Nexus One", I can not select a driver in the "driver directory" of *Android SDK*.

How can I install a driver for Nexus One on Windows 7 so I can use it for USB debugging my Android applications on a real device?
[image: Android SDK and AVD Manager]
[image: Device Manager]

Comment: If you have already installed the adb drivers for another android phone you can go through the advanced driver settings and make it use the existing installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

> The USB driver for Windows is a downloadable component for the Android SDK. If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect an Android-powered device to test your applications, then you will need to install the USB driver.
>
> This document provides information about the latest version of the USB driver and a guide to installing the driver on your development computer.
>
> ---
>
> **USB Driver for Windows, Revision 3 (January 2010)**
>    Adds support for the Nexus One.
>
> ---
>
> The USB Driver for Windows is
>   available for download as an optional
>   SDK component. You need the driver
>   only if you are developing on Windows
>   and want to connect an Android-powered
>   device to your development environment
>   over USB.
>
> To install the driver or upgrade your
>   existing driver to the latest
>   revision, you must first download the
>   driver to your development computer.
>
> To download the driver, use the
>   Android SDK and AVD Manager tool that
>   is included with the Android SDK. If
>   you haven't yet installed the Android
>   SDK, as described in [Installing the
>   Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html), please do so before
>   continuing with the driver
>   installation.
>
> When you are ready to download the
>   driver, follow the instructions given
>   in [Adding SDK Components](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html) to launch the
>   Android SDK and AVD Manager. From the
>   Available Packages panel, select "Usb
>   Driver Package" and download it to
>   your computer. The driver files are
>   downloaded into the `<sdk>\usb_driver`
>   directory.
>
> After the download, follow the
>   instructions below to install or
>   upgrade the driver, based on your
>   needs and Windows operating system
>   version. If you are connecting an
>   Android-powered device to your
>   computer for the first time, follow
>   the below procedure to "Perform a
>   fresh installation." If you have
>   installed one of the older USB drivers
>   and would like to upgrade to the
>   latest version, follow the procedure
>   to "Upgrade an existing driver."
>
> Once you've completed the USB driver
>   installation, please see [Developing on
>   a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for other important
>   information about using an
>   Android-powered device for
>   development.

Comment: My installation did not automatically find the device drivers. I had to go into device driver and manually tell it to search for a device driver in this folder: c:/program files/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/usb-driver/

Comment: Note that this answer is [no longer correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6498538/1269037). The USB drivers are no longer in the `extras` directory of the SDK.

Comment: They're currently in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2013, you don't need to install any Nexus One driver - Windows 7 is able to install the driver online automatically if you allow it. The driver will be named `Android Composite ADB Interface`:

[image: Android Composite ADB Interface]

Just make sure to let Windows install drivers from Windows Update: type "Change device installation settings" in the Start search field and check "Install driver software from Windows Update  if it is not found on my computer.":

[image]

Why do this? Because you don't have to install the entire Android SDK, or the ~400MB [ADT Bundle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), which (by the way) no longer has the driver files in the `\extras\google\usb_driver\` directory, despite [Google's claim](https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Development and check that USB Debugging enabled.

Danny.

Answer (score -1):

better use a sync product like Dropbox or Fiabee, you'll be able to transfer anything back and forth with no effort, works with all USB cables :)
In the second, you can even synchronize your photos without having to worry about copying them.